# I no longer see the 'cached' link in Google search results

Tags: google, cache

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I bring back the Google “cached version” links?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/20173/how-can-i-bring-back-the-google-cached-version-links)

Until recently when I did a search on Google, many of the results would show a *'cached'* link beneath the main title that when clicked would load the page as was cached by Google's web crawler.

Now this *'cached'* link no longer appears.

I have tried a number of different search subjects in case for some reason the issue was restricted to the certain sites returned in my initial search results but none of the results show the link.

I also looked at the search preferences and couldn't see anything about this. Am I missing something - where has the link gone?

**UPDATE**: This is the same effect as using the 'cache:' command in Google. For example entering the following in the Goolgle search box:

```
cache:www.bbc.co.uk
```

will display Google's cached copy of the page.
**This used to be available as a link in the search results**
If it has simply been removed by Google then fine. However I have posted the question in case I can re-enable it thorough a preference or setting somewhere that I have missed.

Comment: Look under the instant previews that pop up on the right when you mouse over a result

Comment: I don't see the link there...

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: I get "cached" as a link within my search results just now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I am using Firefox 3.6.2 and for some reason the cached link does not appear. Neither does the 'Similar' link.

**However when viewing the same search results in IE, both links are there.**

So I can only assume something odd is happening in my local installation of Firefox or for some reason that particular version of Firefox removes the links.

Anyway, thank you to everyone who attempted to help and apologies for leading you on a wild goose chase.

Comment: Can't comment specifically on the cache link but results may vary for a specific query if you are signed into Google while searching.

Answer (score 0):

Hover your cursor over the link. You will see the cache on the right side of the link.

[image]

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Comment: -1: This answer is obsolete.