# How can I bring back the Google "cached version" links?

Tags: google-search

Since Google Search switched to the new layout, two things have been bothering me immensely. One is the absence of "cached version" links which are ocasionally very useful. How do I bring them back? (I know about archive.org, but sometimes this doesn't cut it.)

Another related thing is the live previews of websites which take up the right 1/2 of the results page and I don't want to use them. They steal screen space which I need for actual site text snippets. How can I turn them off?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Actually, the pages previews you dislike so much are your ticket to the cached page version – the link to the cached page has been moved into the preview area:

[image: screenshot of Google cached page link in live preview]

As to the preview itself, there is no way to completely disable it I am aware of. However, if you close a preview by clicking the small closing cross in its right upper corner, previews should only pop up when you hover over the `>>` area to the right of the search results.

Comment: Wow, I never noticed the link, thanks! I know about the close button, the problem is that even after closing the preview it still takes up all the precious screen space. I'll wait for more input on this issue and in case there's nothing useful I'll accept your question.

Comment: Actually, I’d suggest you split off the second part of your question – that is an issue best addressed with [browser extensions](http://sites.google.com/site/mfrelink/) or [UserScripts](http://userscripts.org/scripts/show/109028).

Comment: … and that part actually would belong on SU :P.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the only way around it is by searching with `cache:` in the search field

Comment: Actually, the link is still there – in the preview panel :). See my answer.

Comment: Oh I never saw that either, I hate those screenshots so I never really ever open them.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Firefox or Pale Moon, this bit of code will work with your usercontent.css file.

```
@-moz-document domain(google.com) {
  .vshid { /* Cached links */
      display: block !important;
    }
}
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/dotfiles/blob/d6a9679/mozilla/firefox/chrome/usercontent.css#L74-L77)

Answer (score 1):

More recently, the links with linktext "cached" are back, but in a form that requires JavaScript (for a popup, from *.google.com* domains). See the how-to below and the illustration below.

#### Howto

1. First click on the green arrow to the right of the URL in the search result.
2. Then click on *Cached* (in the popup with *Cached* and *Similar*).

Notes: The *Cached* item in the popup does work as a regular link (for instance, it is possible to open in a separate web tab/page). It opens a page on domain *webcache.googleusercontent.com*. In addition, *Similar* is absent for some search results.

#### Illustration

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [google cache comeback](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/725-google-cache-comeback) user script for Greasemonkey, Tampermonkey or similar browser extensions.

> Appends link to cached version of page to each item in the search results list.
>
> [image]
>
> also affects cached pages in two ways:
>   1. replaces internal links with references inside the displayed page
>   2. for external links, adds references to their cached versions
>
> [image]

Answer (score -2):

There is a website that helps you get the cached version from the url. 
It is handy to have some times.

[cachedview.com](https://cachedview.com)